# Update the total order amount using JavaScript according to selected inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

To give overview, I've just started building this website and wanted to take a different approach to building a form for onboarding / purchasing a service.

I've tried about 10 different approaches in attempts to achieve my desired behaviour but still nothing is working how I expected.

```js
const packageTypes = document.querySelectorAll('.package_type');
const deliveryTimeSelect = document.querySelector('#delivery_time');
const providerSelect = document.querySelector('#provider');
const uniqueTemplatesInput = document.querySelector('#unique_templates');

function updateOrderTotal() {
  // Get the value of the selected package type
  let packageTypeValue = 0;
  packageTypes.forEach((packageType) => {
    const radio = packageType.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked');
    if (radio) {
      packageTypeValue = parseFloat(radio.value);
    }
  });

  // Get the value of the delivery time select box
  const deliveryTimeValue = parseFloat(deliveryTimeSelect.value) || 0;

  // Get the value of the provider select box
  const providerValue = parseFloat(providerSelect.value) || 0;

  // Get the value of the unique templates input
  const uniqueTemplatesValue = parseFloat(uniqueTemplatesInput.value) || 0;

  // Calculate the order total
  const orderTotal = (packageTypeValue + deliveryTimeValue + providerValue) * uniqueTemplatesValue;

  // Update the order_total div with the calculated value
  const orderTotalDiv = document.querySelector('#order_total');
  orderTotalDiv.innerHTML = orderTotal.toFixed(2);
}

// Add event listeners to the delivery time, provider, and unique templates select boxes
deliveryTimeSelect.addEventListener('change', updateOrderTotal);
providerSelect.addEventListener('change', updateOrderTotal);
uniqueTemplatesInput.addEventListener('input', updateOrderTotal);

// Loop over all package_type divs
packageTypes.forEach((packageType) => {
  // Add a click event listener to each package_type div
  packageType.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // Remove the "selected" class from all package_type divs
    packageTypes.forEach((p) => {
      p.classList.remove('selected');
    });

    // Add the "selected" class to the clicked package_type div
    packageType.classList.add('selected');

    // Update the order total whenever the package type is changed
    updateOrderTotal();
  });

  // Add a change event listener to each radio button
  const radio = packageType.querySelector('input[type="radio"]');
  radio.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    // Update the order total whenever a radio button is selected
    updateOrderTotal();
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Code:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
@import url('grid.css');
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 24px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', Sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #0E1C1B;
  font-smooth: always;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0E1C1B;
  border: solid 1px #0E1C1B;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  -moz-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

button:hover {
  border: solid 1px #00F0E2;
  color: #00F0E2;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  -moz-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

button:disabled,
button[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.2;
  cursor: no-drop;
}

.mar-left-16 {
  margin-left: 16px !important;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: #0E1C1B;
  border: solid 1px #0E1C1B;
  padding: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  -moz-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  -moz-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 66%;
  color: #0E1C1B;
  border: solid 1px #0E1C1B;
  font-family: inherit;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  -moz-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 48px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.step_title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #0E1C1B;
  margin-top: 64px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  clear: both;
}

.step_count {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px !important;
  background-color: #00F0E2;
  border-radius: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.packages {
  width: 66%;
  clear: both;
}

.package_type {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  height: 160px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px #0E1C1B;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.package_type:hover {
  background-color: #00F0E2;
}

.package_type:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.package_type:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: none;
}

.package_type input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.package_type label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.package_type.selected {
  background-color: #00F0E2;
}

.package_type h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

.package_type p {
  text-align: center;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.quantity {
  position: relative;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.quantity input {
  width: 66%;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 1.65;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #0E1C1B;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.quantity input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.quantity-nav {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 42px;
}

.quantity-button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #0E1C1B;
  width: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "FontAwesome" !important;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.quantity-button:active {
  background: #EAEAEA;
}

.quantity-button.quantity-up {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0E1C1B;
  border-top: 1px solid #0E1C1B;
  border-right: 1px solid #0E1C1B;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
  line-height: 1.6
}

.quantity-button.quantity-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50%;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0E1C1B;
  border-right: 1px solid #0E1C1B;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px;
  line-height: 24px;
  resize: none;
  min-height: 240px;
  border: solid 1px #0E1C1B;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #0E1C1B;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

#order_screen textarea {
  width: 66%;
}

.upload_btn {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.screen_contain {
  position: relative;
}

#order_summary_parent {
  width: 100%;
}

#order_summary {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 63px;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #0E1C1B;
  min-height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#order_summary h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin: 0;
}

#order_summary button {
  background-color: #00F0E2;
  color: #0E1C1B;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 64px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 86px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .packages {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .package_type {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .package_type:nth-child(2) {
    border-left: solid 1px #0E1C1B;
    border-top: none;
  }
  #order_screen textarea {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .upload_btn {
    width: 100%;
  }
  select {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .quantity input {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #order_summary {
    position: static;
    right: 0;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0E1C1B;
    min-height: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 24px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 64px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
  Place your email template order here
</h2>
<div id="email_template_order">
  <div class="screen_contain">

    <div class="step_title">
      <div class="step_count">
        1
      </div>Choose your package
    </div>
    <div class="packages">
      <label for="code_only_email">
    <div class="package_type">
      <input id="code_only_email" name="package_type_1" type="radio" value="50.00"> </label>
      <h1>
        Code Only
      </h1>
      <p>
        We’ll hand code your designs to HTML
      </p>
    </div>
    </label>
    <label for="code_design_email">
    <div class="package_type">
      <input id="code_design_email" name="package_type_2" type="radio" value="130.00">
      <h1>
        Design + Code
      </h1>
      <p>
       We’ll create eye catching designs & then code them into HTML for you
      </p>
    </div>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="step_title">
    <div class="step_count">
      2
    </div>Number of unique templates
  </div>
  <div class="quantity">
    <input max="9" min="1" step="1" id="unique_templates" type="number" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="step_title">
    <div class="step_count">
      3
    </div>Delivery time
  </div>
  <div id="deliveryTime">
    <div class="custom-select">
      <select id="delivery_time">
        <option>
          Select time:
        </option>
        <option value="72">
          72 hrs (&pound;48)
        </option>
        <option value="48">
          48 hrs (&pound;56)
        </option>
        <option value="24">
          24 hrs (&pound;75)
        </option>
        <option value="12">
          12 hrs (&pound;99)
        </option>
        <option value="8">
          8 hrs (&pound;112)
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="step_title">
      <div class="step_count">
        4
      </div>Email Service Provider
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="email_provider">
    <div class="custom-select">
      <select id="provider">
        <option>
          Select Provider:
        </option>
        <option name="adestra" value="31">
          Adestra (&pound;31)
        </option>
        <option name="exacttarget" value="31">
          Exact Target SFMC (&pound;31)
        </option>
        <option name="campaignmonitor" value="23">
          Campaign Monitor (&pound;23)
        </option>
        <option name="mailchimp" value="23">
          Mailchimp (&pound;23)
        </option>
        <option name="other" value="40">
          Other (&pound;40)
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="step_title">
    <div class="step_count">
      5
    </div>Interactive Add-Ons
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="step_title">
    <div class="step_count">
      6
    </div>Project details
  </div>
  <textarea placeholder="Kindly share detailed information regarding usage/coding standards of this Email. Attach design files in layered PSD/AI/EPS/PDF/SKETCH/ZIP format."></textarea>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="step_title">
    <div class="step_count">
      7
    </div>Supply brief
  </div>
  <button class="upload_btn">Upload brief for this email template</button>
  <input type="checkbox" style="width: auto; margin-left: 16px; margin-right: 16px;">I do not want to upload a brief.
  <div id="order_summary_parent">

    <div id="order_summary">
      <h1>Order summary</h1>
      &pound;<span id="order_total">0</span>
      <button>Complete order</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am expecting to be able to update order_total automatically when something is changed in the form.. If the package_type is changed, the order_total updates, etc etc..

So far, if you click a package type, in this example the packages are called "code only" and "code and design", it will update the order_total the first time you click them, but if you toggle between then again, nothing changes.. also, I can't seem to get the order total to multiple by the input id "unique_templates", it only seems to update when I select another input first, then hit the multiplier, then select another input, then it works. (CONFUSING Ey.)

I just want it to be super simple and I think I've over complicated this all a little.

Everything is in here to see an example of my problem

Comment: One thing, not related to your problem probably, is that you shouldn't need to call `updateOrderTotal` in your `packageType` click handler. You already have the radio button wrapped in a label so the change event should fire automatically when the label is clicked.

Comment: Oh, I see now. The easiest fix is to ensure that both radio buttons have the same `name`. This will allow the browser to enforce that only one can be selected and will unselect the other automatically.

Comment: @ChrisHaas wow that was an easy fix! I'm pretty sure I started off with it like that.. these things can end up like rubix cubes lol

Answer (score 0):

@ChrisHaas kindly solved the issue.

It was as simple as the radio button names needing to be the same name.

I also added the updateOrderTotal(); to the btnUp.click and btnDown.click and that solved the quantity issue too.

Thank you for all who took time to read my mess.

Have a great rest of your week.

Answer (score 0):

Just extracted a part of your code to have a better overview.

As already stated, the radio input elements only work if the `name` is the same.

> A radio group is defined by giving each of radio buttons in the group the same name. Once a radio group is established, selecting any radio button in that group automatically deselects any currently-selected radio button in the same group.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

Also, you do not need two event listeners for `'change'` and for `'click'`, one is enough.

```js
const packageTypes = document.querySelectorAll('.package_type');

function updateOrderTotal() {
  // Get the value of the selected package type
  let packageTypeValue = 0;
  packageTypes.forEach((packageType) => {
    const radio = packageType.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked');
    if (radio) {
      packageTypeValue = parseFloat(radio.value);
    }
  });


  // Calculate the order total
  const orderTotal = packageTypeValue;

  // Update the order_total div with the calculated value
  const orderTotalDiv = document.querySelector('#order_total');
  orderTotalDiv.innerHTML = orderTotal.toFixed(2);
}


// Loop over all package_type divs
packageTypes.forEach((packageType) => {
  // Add a click event listener to each package_type div
  packageType.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // Remove the "selected" class from all package_type divs
    packageTypes.forEach((p) => {
      p.classList.remove('selected');
    });

    // Add the "selected" class to the clicked package_type div
    packageType.classList.add('selected');
    // Update the order total whenever the package type is changed
    updateOrderTotal();
  });

  // Add a change event listener to each radio button
  // not needed
  // const radio = packageType.querySelector('input[type="radio"]');
  // radio.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  // Update the order total whenever a radio button is selected
  //updateOrderTotal();
  // });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Code:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
@import url('grid.css');
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 24px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', Sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #0E1C1B;
  font-smooth: always;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0E1C1B;
  border: solid 1px #0E1C1B;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  -moz-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

button:hover {
  border: solid 1px #00F0E2;
  color: #00F0E2;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  -moz-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

button:disabled,
button[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.2;
  cursor: no-drop;
}

.mar-left-16 {
  margin-left: 16px !important;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: #0E1C1B;
  border: solid 1px #0E1C1B;
  padding: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  -moz-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  -moz-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 66%;
  color: #0E1C1B;
  border: solid 1px #0E1C1B;
  font-family: inherit;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  -moz-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 48px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.step_title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #0E1C1B;
  margin-top: 64px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  clear: both;
}

.step_count {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px !important;
  background-color: #00F0E2;
  border-radius: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.packages {
  width: 66%;
  clear: both;
}

.package_type {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  height: 160px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px #0E1C1B;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.package_type:hover {
  background-color: #00F0E2;
}

.package_type:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.package_type:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: none;
}

.package_type input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.package_type label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.package_type.selected {
  background-color: #00F0E2;
}

.package_type h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

.package_type p {
  text-align: center;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.quantity {
  position: relative;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.quantity input {
  width: 66%;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 1.65;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #0E1C1B;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.quantity input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.quantity-nav {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 42px;
}

.quantity-button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #0E1C1B;
  width: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "FontAwesome" !important;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.quantity-button:active {
  background: #EAEAEA;
}

.quantity-button.quantity-up {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0E1C1B;
  border-top: 1px solid #0E1C1B;
  border-right: 1px solid #0E1C1B;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
  line-height: 1.6
}

.quantity-button.quantity-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50%;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0E1C1B;
  border-right: 1px solid #0E1C1B;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px;
  line-height: 24px;
  resize: none;
  min-height: 240px;
  border: solid 1px #0E1C1B;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #0E1C1B;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

#order_screen textarea {
  width: 66%;
}

.upload_btn {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.screen_contain {
  position: relative;
}

#order_summary_parent {
  width: 100%;
}

#order_summary {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 63px;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #0E1C1B;
  min-height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#order_summary h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin: 0;
}

#order_summary button {
  background-color: #00F0E2;
  color: #0E1C1B;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 64px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 86px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .packages {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .package_type {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .package_type:nth-child(2) {
    border-left: solid 1px #0E1C1B;
    border-top: none;
  }
  #order_screen textarea {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .upload_btn {
    width: 100%;
  }
  select {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .quantity input {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #order_summary {
    position: static;
    right: 0;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0E1C1B;
    min-height: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 24px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 64px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
  Place your email template order here
</h2>
<div id="email_template_order">
  <div class="screen_contain">

    <div class="step_title">
      <div class="step_count">
        1
      </div>Choose your package
    </div>
    <div class="packages">
      <label for="code_only_email">
    <div class="package_type">
      <input id="code_only_email" name="package_type" type="radio" value="50.00"> </label>
      <h1>
        Code Only
      </h1>
      <p>
        We’ll hand code your designs to HTML
      </p>
    </div>
    </label>
    <label for="code_design_email">
    <div class="package_type">
      <input id="code_design_email" name="package_type" type="radio" value="130.00">
      <h1>
        Design + Code
      </h1>
      <p>
       We’ll create eye catching designs & then code them into HTML for you
      </p>
    </div>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div id="order_summary_parent">

    <div id="order_summary">
      <h1>Order summary</h1>
      &pound;<span id="order_total">0</span>
      <button>Complete order</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```